# Definite integration of spherical Bessel function of radical argument

Tags: integration, radicals, bessel-functions, spherical-harmonics

I have to solve some integrals of the form:
$$\int_0^{x_0} dx \, j_n( R ) \cdot \frac{p(x)}{R^n}$$ where $R=\sqrt{x^2 + 2 a c x + c^2}$ , $j_n$ is the spherical Bessel function of order n, p(x) is a  polynomial and $|a|<1$.

I have tried changing variable from x to R but this doesn't work: e.g. for the simple case $n=0$ and $p(x)=1$, I obtain something like:
$$\int dR \, j_0( R ) \cdot \frac{R}{\sqrt{(R-bc )(R+bc)}} = \int dR \, \frac{\sin(R)}{\sqrt{(R-bc )(R+bc)}}$$
with $b=(1-a^2)$.

Similar integrals of the type
$$\int_0^{x_0} dx \,  \frac{ j_n( x ) }{(x)^m}$$
with $m \le n$ are easily solvable expressing the Bessel functions in terms of sine and cosine and then integrating by parts, but, with the radical in the argument of the Bessel function, things get harder.
Do you have any idea to manage that?

Comment: Also, look up this method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Comment: I edited the question and inserted the results you asked for. Thank you for the advice of Euler substitution: I've just tried it but I think it doesn't work with trigonometric function.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work with trigonometric function"? It's not supposed to simplify the trig/Bessel function, it's supposed to get rid of the radical, so every argument becomes rational. The Bessel function will still be present, but it will now be of a rational argument, and everything else in the integrand will also be rational. Unlike your initial substitution. Which is why Euler substitution is so powerful. As for the resulting integral, it might not have an exact expression at all

Comment: " it's supposed to get rid of the radical" of course it does, but then it leaves you with a rational argument in the Bessel function of the type $b c \frac{1+t}{1-t}$, and I think that this cannot be integrated.

Comment: It is likely there's no exact expression for the integral in terms of known functions. So you will either need to use numerical methods or some approximation/asymptotic expansion. Depends on the application. Then it may help to have a rational argument. Or not. Again, depends on the particular case